# Graph shortest path?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

I am facing which I believe is a kind of shortest path problem on a graph.

I need to find shortest path from node A to B, considering all edges have positive weight for connected vertexes, ∞ for not connected ones.

Vertexes have variable positive weightes.

The cost of a path is the weight of the vertex with maximum weight considering all vertexes involved in that path.

Should I apply Dijkstra in this situation, and if so how, considering that the weight of each Vertex changes depending on the previous vertexes visited?

Can you point me on how to tackle this problem otherwise?

Comment: Dijkstra keeps discovering new paths and updates nodes weight if greater than previous weight while making tree, Dijkstra is good way to do this . You might wanna look at A* too :)

Comment: "Should I apply Dijkstra in this situation, and if so how, considering that the weight of each Vertex changes depending on the previous vertexes visited?" -> yes weight of each vertex might will change. That's not problem , that algorithm for solving the problem you pasted :)

Comment: Ok, so basically I'll try to apply Dijkstra computing at each step tentative distance for each vertex with my function max(weight(path_vertexes)) instead of simply adding edges and vertex weights to the current path cost like in the basic version of the problem.

Comment: Here is the algorithm : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm. you call that max function of yours relaxation in dijkstra :)

Comment: did you mean all edges have zero weight and all vertices have positive weights?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia Ok. I understood the problem now. As mentioned by Anubis, Dijkstra's Single source shortest path algorithm will work.
For the classical SP problem Dijkstra's algorithm will not work for negative edge weights. But for this problem even if the vertices have -ve weight, it would still work as the distance function is just the max weight of a vertex over all vertex involved in a path.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand if you should consider the weights of the edges,because you said that you want the path with the max/min weight on a vertice possible,from A to B.
My solution for that is to convert every weight on vertex,to a weight on edge , just like in the image:[image]

now you want to find the path from A to B where the the biggest weight on edge is min/max.
you can use MST algotirhm for this,because you dont care about the path lenght,but only the max/min edge cost.